# Is it possible to have a contenteditable div inside a table cell stick to its original cell dimensions?

Tags: html, css, html-table, contenteditable

I'm making an editable cell within a table, however despite `overflow: auto` css typing in there just makes it expand in a very awkward way.

How do I make it stick to the initial cell size, with scroll bars appearing as needed? Preferably this needs to be without set pixel values for width/height, so the whole table will stay on-screen between different resolutions or zooming in and out (control+mousewheel).

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html,
.table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
cell {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Person 1</th>
    <th>Person 2</th>
    <th>Person 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Emil</td>
    <td>Tobias</td>
    <td>Linus</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div contenteditable="true" class="cell">Editable cell</div>
    </td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a `<div>` with `contenteditable="true"`, you can use a `<textarea>` which shows scrollbars once the text goes beyond the boundaries like below.

TIP: Using `<textarea>`, you can increase the number of rows that are visible by default.

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
html,
.table {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
cell {
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr>
    <th>Person 1</th>
    <th>Person 2</th>
    <th>Person 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Emil</td>
    <td>Tobias</td>
    <td>Linus</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <textarea id="w3review" name="w3review" rows="3" cols="50">Editable Text.</textarea>
    </td>
    <td>14</td>
    <td>10</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `<table>`, try using CSS-Grids, as they have the ability to have fixed size and you can do exactly what you ask.

Good resources to start with it are:

- [Grid Garden](https://cssgridgarden.com)
- [CSS-Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/)
- [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/grid)

NOTE: I understand that I don't answer the question as is, but I try to push CSS grids every time someone uses HTML tables for display and alignment, as CSS should be used instead.

Comment: That's probably fine untill an end user asks why it's not possible to copy and paste (parts of) the table to a spreadsheet or text document